# "TypeError: 'null' is not an object" when first time execute code

Tags: python, python-2.7, ghost.py

Ghost is giving me this error when I execute fallowing code:

```
    from ghost import Ghost
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/appBIR/index.aspx"
    ghost = Ghost()

    page, resources = ghost.open(url)
    page, resources = ghost.evaluate(
         "document.getElementById('btnNowaCaptcha').click();")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(ghost.content)
    capcha = soup.find(id='imgCaptch')
```

But when I use pdb and execute once more last two lines everything is fine.
Is anyone know why?

Comment: Let's see the whole stack trace.

Comment: Could it be that it is is too fast? You're evaluating too soon

Comment: Although my gut-feeling would be that the `gost` methods return `null` for some conditions, and you're not checking for that before trying to operate on the returned objects.

Comment: I used time.sleep() but nothing change

Comment: null is not *python*, but javascript.

Comment: Bah, I've been jumping between languages way too much lately. Of course you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the page did not load fully yet, thus `document.getElementById('btnNowaCaptcha')` would return `null`; you should add

```
ghost.wait_for_page_loaded()  # and/or
ghost.wait_for_selector("#btnNowaCaptcha")
```

before the `ghost.evaluate` to make sure that the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately I have still the same error.
`(Pdb) 2015-02-19T21:05:04.1424376304 Ghost(<e9543174-fbcc-4cb3-bd20-d2b1d34581a2>): https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/appBIR/scripts/appbir.js(1500): TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(widocznaKarta).style')`

Comment: So does this give a Python traceback? this just means that the scripts on that page are buggy